# How to disable video after render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am attempting to implement the Instagram like feature that destroys videos (stories) after 24 hrs, but in my case its just the duration of the video. Using this [example](https://mohitk05.github.io/react-insta-stories/) I am trying to allow users to only view a story once, meaning no replay. Even upon refreshing the page, it should not load.I tried localStorage but couldn't work.

Comment: Using localStorage is a bad idea for something like this since the user can just clear the browser Storage. Are the clients logged into an account or do you have any other idea on how you plan identify who has played the video?

Comment: You need to use no-cache in combination with some server-side logic to fetch video so that it get's played only once. Please show some code (a JS fiddle would be wonderful) of what you are trying so that I get help with the specifics.

Comment: I have a list of all the clients names, each user is unique (I am also new to JS). I think most are not able to clear local storage because its on mobile, it would be enough for this execution. I don't have experience with server-side so I avoided it completely. Thanks @Faisal

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can write a foolproof solution to this without some server-side intervention.

Yet, if you think localStorage based frontend solution is enough for you (which I don't recommend), you can:

- Maintain a sorted list of MD5 hash of the videos in your localStorage.
- When your react app loads (in componentDidMount), load that list into memory. Now you can search this ordered list with your current video MD5 hash to decide if you are to play this video of not.
- When you play a video, update the list of MD5 hashes both in memory and localStorage.
- If your server removes the videos after 24 hours or some interval like that, you should store the time in local storage too to cleanup your localStorage or it'll be ever growing in size.

Comment: Hello Mr Faisal actually its just one video, so this is how I tried to make it. I used localStorage for getting currentId of the video, and set it to 2(final id of the last story) so that it should persist after refresh. I don't know how to push it into [component](https://github.com/mohitk05/react-insta-stories/blob/96418e0c07a2474b3fe81e034097740be66478cb/src/components/ProgressArray.js) for persistance

`var currentId = this.state.currentId;
 localStorage.setItem( 'currentId', 2);
      console.log(currentId);`

Comment: Could you make a working JSFiddle with what you've tried for me to look? If you add it to your question, it would be much easier to help you with. Right Now I'm not sure where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You can't truly control that video.  Once it's sent, it's sent and viewable.  But, you can come close.

First, continue with your UI mechanism like you plan to with LocalStorage or similar.  This is to prevent normal users from viewing the video over and over again.

Next, use [Encrypted Media Extensions](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/eme) to implement DRM.  This makes it harder to get at the raw media, and gives you more control over the timing of things.  Note that this is a huge hassle, so make sure it's worth it before you go down this road.